How to combine datasets of different weights using zfit
I have two datasets. Dataset_1, each element of which has the same weight_1, and dataset_2, each element of which has the same weight_2. Weight_2 is larger than weight_1. As a note: I do not know the mu or sigma for either dataset.
I want to combine these datasets and weights so that I can fit a Gaussian to the combined data. I then want to define the negative log likelihood and then minimise this to find the optimal values of mu and sigma.
My problem is that my fitted gaussian is not properly fitting my data. A photo of this is attached. resulting fitting plot
Here is what I have currently:
obs = zfit.Space('obs', limits=(100, 180))
sigma = zfit.Parameter('sigma', 3, 0.01, 4, floating=True)
mu = zfit.Parameter('mu', 130, 100, 200, floating=True)

dataset_1 = zfit.Data(data=data_1, obs=obs, weights=weights_1)
dataset_2 = zfit.Data(data=data_2, obs=obs, weights=weights_2)
combined_data = zfit.data.concat([dataset_1, dataset_2])

gauss = zfit.pdf.Gauss(obs=obs, mu=mu, sigma=sigma)

nll = zfit.loss.UnbinnedNLL(model=gauss, data=combined_data)
minimizer = zfit.minimizer = zfit.minimize.Minuit()
result = minimizer.minimize(nll)

This code gives me the fitted sigma and mu and the plot which I have attached.

What would be the expected outcome? Can you try with the same Gaussian mean? If you have two datasets drawn from two different (is that correct) Gaussian distributions and you fit them with one Gaussian distribution, I expect this to be suboptimal (sidenote, maybe also make sure that the sigma is not at the lower limit)
